# The type or namespace name 'EventHandler' could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using C# with Xamarin, when using EventHandler, I got this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'EventHandler' could not be found(are you missing a using dirrective or an assembly reference?)(CS0246)
```

Here is my code:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Emgu_Hello_World
{
    public class EmptyClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer ();
            Capture capture = new Capture ();
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler (delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame ();
            });
            viewer.ShowDialog ();
        }
    }
}
```

What should I referenced to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EventHandler is defined in System namespace:

```
   using System;
```